# Are there order guarantee with HBase Scan result

Tags: hbase

I would ask, are there order guarantee for the row keys when I iterate the ResultScanner(Scan result), smaller row key comes before larger row key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. As per https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#dm.sort:

> All data model operations HBase return data in sorted order. First by row, then by ColumnFamily, followed by column qualifier, and finally timestamp (sorted in reverse, so newest records are returned first).

Comment: Thanks @ben-waston, great answer!